# Matching phrases within delimiters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, full-text-search, pattern-matching

I am looking to perform an exact match on a phrase within specified delimiters in MySQL.  I have the following data in a full text index field.

> ,garden furniture,patio heaters,best offers,best deals,

I am performing the following query which is returning the aforementioned record.

```
SELECT id, tags
FROM Store 
WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST(',garden,' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I only want to return records which contain the value: `,garden,` not `,garden furniture,` or `,country garden,` etc.

It is currently performing a greedy match and ignoring the comma delimiters specified in the query.  I have attempted to escape the commas to force them to be included in the query, but this does not work.

Is is possible to specify non-alphanumeric delimiters as part of the match?  I want to be able to perform an exact match, like a regular expression i.e `'/,garden,/'`.

Comment: Seems like you are **NOT** using usual normalization to store tags (and you are suffering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html):

Modify a character set file: This requires no recompilation. The `true_word_char()` macro uses a “character type” table to distinguish letters and numbers from other characters. . You can edit the contents of the `<ctype><map>` array in one of the character set XML files to specify that ',' is a “letter.” Then use the given character set for your FULLTEXT indexes. For information about the `<ctype><map>` array format, see Section 9.3.1, “[Character Definition Arrays](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/character-arrays.html)”.

An other option is to [add a new collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-text-adding-collation.html).

Either way, you'll have to rebuild the index:

```
REPAIR TABLE Store QUICK;
```

Comment: @Richard, I would call it a band-aid. Still a very informative answer though. So +1.

Comment: @Richard, this is exactly what you asked for. Although, in agreement with Johan, I suggest you to consider storing tags normalized. This full text search hack might well solve your current problem but there's a chance you'll face many others with this design. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Only `match against` can use an index on your search.
However if your table if not too big, you can use:

```
SELECT id, tags
FROM Store 
WHERE tags LIKE "garden" OR tags LIKE "garden,%" OR tags LIKE "%, garden,%"
```

There are other options (find_in_set), but I really don't want to go into those, because they perform even worse than the above SQL.

**The real problem, never use CSV in a database!**
Use CSV in a database is a really really bad idea, because
• It is wasteful, your data is not normalized
• You cannot join on a CSV field
• You cannot use indexes on a CSV field
• Full-text indexes does not play nice with separators (as you've seen)

The answer to create 2 extra tables.

```
Table tag (innoDB)
----------
id integer primary key auto_increment
tag varchar(50)    //one tag per row!

Table tag_link (innoDB)
--------------
store_id integer foreign key references store(id)
tag_id integer foreign key references tag(id)  
primary key = (store_id + tag_id) //composite PK
```

Now you can easily do all sorts of queries on tags.

```
SELECT s.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.tag) FROM store s
INNER JOIN tag_link tl1 ON (s.id = tl1.store_id)
INNER JOIN tag t1 ON (t1.id = tl1.tag_id)
INNER JOIN tag_link tl2 ON (s.id = tl2.store_id)
INNER JOIN tag t2 ON (t2.id = tl2.tag_id)
WHERE t1.tag = 'garden'
GROUP BY s.id
```

This will select one tag named `garden` *(using t1 and tl1)*, find all stores linked to that tag and then get all tags linked to those stores *(using t2 and tl2)*.
Very fast and very flexible.

Comment: @ajreal, that depends, `find_in_set` will kill any chance of using an index, at least with this code you have a chance of using an index, depending on whether `garden` is the first item or not, which may or may not be relevant depending on the exact strings in the database. Putting CSV is a field is just such a piss poor idea.

Comment: I do agree, convince the OP? (off-topic)

Comment: +1, totally agree with the normalized approach: separate `tag` and `tag_link` table, like in the SO schema (http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new on the left side)